# c# Timer passing string as stateinfo

Tags: c#

I have a question using C# with its `Timers.Timer` class.  Given the below general outline:

1 - Would the `stateinfo` (`new ei.StringID`) be cleaned up automatically by C# at some point?

2 - When does it clean it up?

```
class A {
  Timer m_Timer;
  int m_JustForShow;

  public void TimerHandler(Object stateinfo) {
    // is this right?
    string id=(string) stateinfo;
    // use id to check if action has completed and if not
    // we cancel it.
    if (m_JustForShow==1) {
      // Is this running under the objects context and I can just do this?
    }
  }

  public void MyEventNotification(in MyEventInfo ei)
  {
    if (ei.State!=MyEventState.Completed) {
      m_Timer=new Timer(TimerHandler, new ei.StringID, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does `new ei.StringID` even mean here? That doesn't look like it would compile...

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes
2. When the Garbage Collector feels like it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering the question in your commented code,

> ```
> // is this right?
> string id=(string) stateinfo;
> ```

No, in general you'd better use `.ToString()` to get the string representation of an object. If the type if object itself, you can use `.GetHashInfo()` to get a unique code for a particular instance.

Moreover, the signature `public void MyEventNotification(in MyEventInfo ei)` is wrong. You don't need to pass any parameter:

```
class A
{
    Timer m_Timer;
    int m_JustForShow;

    public void TimerHandler(object stateInfo)
    {
        // is this right?
        string id = stateInfo.GetHashCode().ToString();

        // use id to check if action has completed and if not
        // we cancel it.
        if (m_JustForShow == 1)
        {
            // Is this running under the objects context and I can just do this?
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"This is the stateInfo object {id}");
    }

    public void MyEventNotification()
    {
        var state = new object();

        m_Timer = new Timer(this.TimerHandler, state, 1000, 1000);
    }
}
```